# How to synthesize tables using pandas

Tags: pandas

[image]

Hopefully the image is working but that's what I'm trying to do, get all the John's to come up only once but also be connected to all other details.

Comment: `df=df.set_index(['Name','Accounts'])` or `df.groupby(['Name','Accounts'],as_index=False).first()`?

Comment: Index makes things unique right?

Comment: yes it  makes entry unique....but it will be easy to understand that what you want If you post a sample dataframe as text and your expected output from that sample dataframe

Comment: I am not sure how this would look as a dataframe